# mp3 that will not play due to sketchy copy over to ssd

Tags: mp3

Hi so  got a lil question here, can anybody advise me on a program that will scan folders of mp3 and auto remove the ones that will not play, Iv got way to many to do it my hand 1 by 1. Thanks for any info aswell. peace.

Comment: Whether or not it plays is dependent on the player.  Most MP3 players will happily decode and play glitchy MP3 files.  So, there isn't a hard and fast scan you can do.

Comment: Maybe there's a consistent way these files have been corrupted?  Null bytes maybe?